# How to use an icon from windows shell32.dll for an Inno Setup shortcut

Tags: icons, inno-setup

I have seen some Inno Setup installer that assign an icon from `shell32.dll` to one or more of its shortcuts, in the desktop or in the start menu.

The question is how to assign one of theses to any shortcut that I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to `shell32.dll` in [`IconFilename` parameter of your `[Icons]` section entry](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=iconssection&anchor=IconFilename):

```
[Icons]
Name: "{userdesktop}\My Program"; Filename: "{app}\MyProg.exe"; \
    IconFilename: "shell32.dll"; IconIndex: 12
```

[image]